# How to implement a menu using the composite pattern?

Tags: c++, menu, composite

I am trying to implement a `menu` using the `Composite Pattern`, similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037164/data-structure-to-represent-menu-which-can-have-submenu/13037248#13037248).

The `Component` declares several functions that `Composite` and `Leaf` have in common as pure virtual. The implementation there is not a problem.

Because my `"Client"` class needs to have access to all of the non common functions that are only used in the `Composite` (addChild, getChild, setSelectedItemNumber, etc...), I needed to move them into the `Component`. And this causes a problem. If I get it right, I have to declare them also as pure virtual, but then I need to do implementations in the `Leaf` that don't make any sense there.

Another possible solution might be to do an implementation of these functions in the `Component`. But then I end up having a tight coupling between the `Component` and the `Composite` because they need to hold a pointer to each other. Plus I am not sure if having this pointer in the Interface is such a good idea.

I think both solutions are bad, so I'm hoping someone can point me the right way to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

So here is my code. I have a class MenuComponent which is the `Component` (interface):

```
class MenuComponent
{
public:
    virtual ~MenuComponent() { };

    // placeholder for some pure virtual functions
    virtual MenuComponent* getChild(int position) const;
    virtual void addChild(MenuComponent* child);
    virtual int getSelectedItemNumber() const;
    virtual void setSelectedItemNumber(const int& selectedItemNumber);
    virtual int getNumberOfMenuItems() const;
};
```

A class Menu which is the `Composite`:

```
class Menu : public MenuComponent
{

public:
    Menu(Menu* parent, int menuType, int selectedItemNumber, int numberOfMenuItems, int menuId);

    // placeholder for declaration of the pure virtual functions from the interface
    MenuComponent* getChild(int position) const;
    void addChild(MenuComponent* menu);
    int getSelectedItemNumber() const;
    void setSelectedItemNumber(const int& selectedItemNumber);
    int getNumberOfMenuItems() const;

private:
    // placeholder for member variables for the implementation of the pure virtual functions
    int selectedItemNumber_;
    int numberOfMenuItems_;

    std::vector<MenuComponent*> childs_;
};
```

And of course a class MenuItem which is the `Leaf`:

```
class MenuItem : public MenuComponent
{

public:
    MenuItem(Menu* parent, int menuType, int menuId);

    // placeholder for declaration of the pure virtual functions from the interface
    int getActiveItem() const;
    void setActiveItem(const int activeItem);   

private:
    // placeholder for member variables for the implementation of the pure virtual 
    int activeItem_;
};
```

Comment: The whole point of the composite pattern, is that everything is a component type.  Your `MenuItem` is not part of the hierarchy.

Comment: I think it should be a component type. That's how I declared it after understanding the link I provided in the first line. I just forgot ": public MenuComponent"

Answer (score 0):

If your "Client" needs to have access to the composite, it should hold a (smart)pointer, or a reference, to a `Menu`. And not to a `MenuComponent`.

You misunderstood the purpose of `MenuComponent` here. It's not an abstract interface for clients to operate on the entire menu functionality, it's an interface to operate on menu *structure*.

The GoF therefore listed it the "Structural Patterns" section of their book.

Comment: Are you sure about that? [Here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) they say the following about the client (App): "manipulates objects in the composition through the Component interface."
Plus, how do I walk through the childs then in my "Client", when I only have a pointer to a `Menu`? Every child can either be a Menu or a MenuItem. That's why I think I need the pointer to a `MenuComponent`

Comment: @Oliver, yes I'm sure. Also, your abstract component class & composite class are defined backwards, now that I think about it. It's `Menu` that should have `addChild` and not `MenuComponent`. A leaf has no meaningful implementation of `addChild`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the GoF. There are two different variants of this pattern. Safety and transparency. So we are both right. The changes you are pointing me to are for the safety variant which according to the GoF has the problem that eveytime you have to find out if the `Component` is a `Composite` or a `Leaf`. After that you might need a Downcast in order to access the methods of the `Composite`.

Comment: The second variant (transparency) is what I implemented and was questioning. It has the advantage that you don't need to know what kind of `Component` it is that you are trying to access, but it has the problem that you got unuseful and mostly empty methods in the `Leaf`. So for the "Client" it can happen that a function call has no effect.

Comment: @Oliver, I understand your dilemma. But I think it largely depends on how you build your menu, rather than how you use the tree afterwards. If you build it from the top down, than you can use the safety variant.